# SQL Server : grant insert permission

Tags: sql-server

Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to `sa`, `dbo`, entity owner, `information_schema`, `sys`, or yourself.

Gives message while executing the following commands..

```
use master
Go

GRANT Insert ON [dbo].[emp_bonus] to mansi
Go
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** message ?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

You must use your database in order to set permission.

```
use YourDatabase
Go

GRANT Insert ON YourObject to YourUser
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the database correctly in the "Available Databases" drop down. It is near Execute button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the that you are the db owner and being the db owner of the database,  you don't need to grant any permission for the db.

You may check [Find out SQL Server Logins and associated Server Roles](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84ddd8e2-e8eb-4b36-beba-5ae51ca46c8c/find-out-sql-server-logins-and-associated-server-roles?forum=transactsql)

Also as mehdi pointed if you have not set the database of your table where you want to set the role then also you may get this message.

You need to change that as well and try again:

```
use DatabaseName
Go
GRANT Insert ON [dbo].[emp_bonus] to mansi
Go
```